# The android virtual machine it suddenly disappears and doesn't report any errors when I set up react-native-webrtc

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webrtc

**Goal**

I'm new to react native and I would like to install react-native-webrtc

**Problem**

I can install on IOS but I cannot install it on android

**What I did**

step 1: npx react-native init AwesomeProject

step 2: npm install react-native-webrtc --save

step 3: Installation on IOS (https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/iOSInstallation.md)

step 4: Installation on Android (https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/AndroidInstallation.md)

**Result**

When I "npm run ios" it's ok

When I "npm run android" it appears and disappears and I don't know why, there is not error log in terminal